# how to get instant update or url changes in MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get always location update if any changes in url (eg. queryparams). it can be add or removed. but in this code. i'm getting the first url update on second time changes. I mean, if any change on frist time onUrlChange() is not calling. on second time url changes onUrlChange() getting called. Why? how can get immediate changes?

```
const getCurrentPageURL = () => {
  const currentPageUrl = document.URL;
  console.log(new URL(currentPageUrl))
}

let lastUrl = location.href;
new MutationObserver(() => {
  const url = location.href;
  if (url !== lastUrl) {
    lastUrl = url;
    onUrlChange();
  }
}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

function onUrlChange() {
  console.log("Hit URL");
  getCurrentPageURL();
}
```

Comment: When the URL changes, the page reloads and the current script stops running. So it makes no sense to be notified of this change.

Comment: The exception is if only the hash part of the URL changes, this doesn't reload, it just scrolls to the ID/name in the hash. This triggers the `hashchange` event, you can add a listener for that.